# Global node modules not recognized

Tags: node.js, bash, debian

I am reading around SO and I still can't fix it. I installed Grunt-cli and bower global and when I run it I get

```
bash: grunt: command not found
```

So I didn't have a .`bash_profile` and I added it. And I put this inside:

```
export PATH=/.node/lib/node_modules:$PATH
```

But still not working. If you need the prefix is:

```
prefix = "/root/.node"
```

I am using debian.

Comment: You started a new shell after installing and adding that to your `PATH`? Also did you miss a leading `~` on that `PATH` modification? I expect that was supposed to be `~/.node/...` and not `/.node` for a `.node` directory in your home directory and not one in the system root (`/`) directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with brew install.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-linux

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to reload your bash profile after creating it? If not, just open a terminal and type `source ~/.bash_profile`

This will exit the shell and log you back in so that it can recognize changes made to it.

Comment: Yes I did, but  I solved the problem with brew install. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-linux